# How do I pass a Texture2D into Android and save it as a Bitmap?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I have a unity scene where I want to pass a Texture2D into android, do some processing, then save it as a bitmap. My code isn't working. For simplicity sake i removed the processing part of it and I'm trying to just save the image as a bitmap.

On the unity side there's some initialization for the android package and this line:

```
_pluginInterface.CallStatic("ProcessImage", testTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr().ToInt32(), testTexture.width, testTexture.height);
```

On the Java side:

```
public static void ProcessImage(int ptr, int width, int height){
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  // this is just so I get the right length  
    int byteCount = b.getByteCount();
    ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteCount);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, ptr);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, inputBuffer);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    inputBuffer.rewind();
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(inputBuffer);
    SaveToFileDebug(bmp); // basic function that saves the bitmap
}
```

As you can probably tell I'm all over the place with the encodings and i think that might be the problem, but they don't seem to match between unity and android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rabbid76 so what reads a texture?

Comment: That is beyond my knowledge of GL. Do you have some code showing this?

Comment: Are you abled to solve it ?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing such acrobatics coding just use GetRawTextureData and use the returned byte array to create your bitmap

### Example

```
byte[] raw = testTexture.GetRawTextureData();
_plugin.Interface.CallStatic("YourMethod",raw,width, height);
```

### Java Side

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(raw, 0, raw.length)
```

Comment: I think you might be thinking of transferring the bitmap in the opposite direction. I want to send it from unity->android , not from android->unity

Comment: It's clear I've updated my answer to clarify my thoughts.

Comment: I'm doing that now as an alternative. Except you cant use GetRawTextureData, you must encode it to JPG or PNG (like tex.EncodeToJPG(10)). The encoding is fast but passing so much data as an argument is pretty slow.